# How to remove .xml and .json from url when using active resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I do a mapping in active resource, its default request to the Ruby on Rails always automatically add the extension at the end of the url.
For example:
I want to get user resource from Ruby on Rails by mapping as below:

```
class user < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = 'http://localhost:3000'
end
```

And something that I need, I just want it pass the url without extension like

```
http://localhost:3000/user
```

In contrast it automatically adds the extension at the end of the url like

```
http://localhost:3000/user.xml
```

How can I omit the extension of the url when I make request from the active resource mapping?

Answer (score 16):

At first, I did use @Joel AZEMAR's answer and it worked quite well until I started using PUT. 
Doing a PUT added in the .json/.xml.

A bit of [research here](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/blob/master/lib/active_resource/base.rb#L295), revealed that using the `ActiveResource::Base#include_format_in_path` option worked far better for me.

**Without include_format_in_path:**

```
class Foo < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = 'http://localhost:3000'
end

Foo.element_path(1)
=> "/foo/1.json"
```

**With include_format_in_path:**

```
class Foo < ActiveResource::Base
  self.include_format_in_path = false
  self.site = 'http://localhost:3000'
end

Foo.element_path(1)
=> "/foo/1"
```

Comment: This works well, and is much cleaner than the other solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by overriding two ActiveResource's methods in your class:

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
  class << self
    def element_path(id, prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
      prefix_options, query_options = split_options(prefix_options) if query_options.nil?
      "#{prefix(prefix_options)}#{collection_name}/#{id}#{query_string(query_options)}"
    end

    def collection_path(prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
      prefix_options, query_options = split_options(prefix_options) if query_options.nil?
      "#{prefix(prefix_options)}#{collection_name}#{query_string(query_options)}"
    end
  end

  self.site = 'http://localhost:3000'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override methods of ActiveResource::Base

Add this lib in /lib/active_resource/extend/ directory don't forget uncomment
**"config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)"** in *config/application.rb*

```
module ActiveResource #:nodoc:
  module Extend
    module WithoutExtension
      module ClassMethods
        def element_path_with_extension(*args)
          element_path_without_extension(*args).gsub(/.json|.xml/,'')
        end
        def new_element_path_with_extension(*args)
          new_element_path_without_extension(*args).gsub(/.json|.xml/,'')
        end
        def collection_path_with_extension(*args)
          collection_path_without_extension(*args).gsub(/.json|.xml/,'')
        end
      end

      def self.included(base)
        base.class_eval do
          extend ClassMethods
          class << self
            alias_method_chain :element_path, :extension
            alias_method_chain :new_element_path, :extension
            alias_method_chain :collection_path, :extension
          end
        end
      end  
    end
  end  
end
```

in model

```
class MyModel < ActiveResource::Base
  include ActiveResource::Extend::WithoutExtension
end
```