# Active resource rails not fetching data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, activeresource

**This is active.rb**

```
class Active < ActiveResource::Base
    self.site = "http://localhost:3002/api/v1/users" # **When i run this it is not fetching data**

    self.site = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://localhost:3002/api/v1/users")) # **When i run this i can see the data in console. Will get error Bad URI**

end
```

**welcome_controller.rb**

```
 def index
    @active = Active.all
  end
```

**I am Unable to fetch data from the using active resource. Please let me know
Thank you**

Comment: Please add some more info for us to answer this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that ActiveResource is not making the request you are expecting. You can get some clarity by running the following in the Rails console:

`Active.collection_path` and `Active.element_path`

for the former you will see `"/api/v1/users/actives.json"` as activeresource expects the class Active to be the name of your resource.

You can control the URI generated and remove the resource specification (ie .json) by [overriding two of the ActiveResource methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070148/3258059)

```
class Active < ActiveResource::Base

  class << self
    def element_path(id, prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
      prefix_options, query_options = split_options(prefix_options) if query_options.nil?
      "#{prefix(prefix_options)}#{id}#{query_string(query_options)}"
    end

    def collection_path(prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
      prefix_options, query_options = split_options(prefix_options) if query_options.nil?
      "#{prefix(prefix_options)}#{query_string(query_options)}"
    end
  end
  self.site = "http://localhost:3002/"
  self.prefix = "/api/v1/users"
end
```

This would then give you a collection path of `/api/v1/users`

Perhaps a cleaner option would be to use `self.element_name = "users"`, the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) indicates that this " In the case where you already have an existing model with the same name as the desired RESTful resource"

You can also remove the format (.json) by using `self.include_format_in_path = false` as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434402/3258059).

So you could have the same affect by using:

```
class Active < ActiveResource::Base
  self.include_format_in_path = false
  self.site = "http://localhost:3002/"
  self.prefix = "/api/v1/"
  self.element_name = "users"
end
```

Just as an aside I'd like to link to this answer which has some extremely useful [notes on customising ActiveResource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803902/3258059) without recourse to monkey patching.